# Subdivide a face into smaller faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

Here is my sphere:

[image: In the Edit mode]

I want to subdivide the face I'm selecting into four, like I did with the other ones. But, when I go to W->Subdivide Smooth, the surrounding dots just move closer to the face, and the face doesn't subdivide in four. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the faces you're subdividing are NGons, not quads or tris, because you subdivided the surrouding faces. Subdividing them adds vertices but no edge.
[image: NGon problem]

What you can do is dissolving the non desired vertices with <kbd>X</kbd>
[image: dissolve]

Then joining them to make edge and faces, select 2 vertices and hit <kbd>J</kbd>
[image: join]

subdivide smooth on the new edge and join
[image: subd join]

[image: final join]