# can't subdivide face

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can't subdivide the front face in a model. I want to put more materials on the model, I used a Boolean modifier, and caused triangle faces. I don't know if that makes any difference but I need to subdivide it so badly it's getting on my nerves.

Thank you

Here's a picture of the model
[image]

Comment: it's probably because it's an ngon,try subdividing manually with the knife tool

Comment: Big ugly n-gon...  Delete it,  select then the vertices on the edge and do grid fill to go create quads.

Comment: Do you mean the whole object or the face

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53130/subdivide-a-face-into-smaller-faces. To be able to subdivide face there, you need another kind of topology in that region. It's up to you what method to use for that - either deleting face and recreating with GridFill or splitting existing face with Edge tools.

Comment: Boolean modifier does not ensure a "good" inner geometry. In particular when the initial mesh is already dense (as yours seems to be). To me this modifier is often a false good idea when this kind of consequences are not known in advance. As @cegaton said, the best is to delete the face and try a grid fill.

Answer (score 11):

Boolean operations are a convenient way to transform geometry, but they can leave behind other problems. In this case you've generated a big and ugly n-gon (a polygon with more than 4 vertices). Ngons are notorious for deforming in unpredictable or undesirable ways. In general is preferable to [work with quads](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they).

[image]

Start by getting rid of the ngon

[image]

select the edge loop by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while slecting an edge.

[image]

Press the space bar and type grid fill (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and select grid fill)

[image]

And play with the grid fill settings until you get something that does look like a grid.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an N-Gon.

To check if a mesh has N-gons do the following.

- In edit mode go to face selection
- Choose select from your 3d menu bar
- Select All by trait
- Select faces by sides
- In the tool panel set the number of sides to 4(its at the bottom you may have to scroll to see it)
- set the type to greater than

This will show you any face that has mort then 4 sides

Hope it helps